# Class Constructor in lazy-init

Tags: java, spring

I am creating a bean with lazy-init="true" but I don't want constructor of class to be invoked. But somehow with lazy-init too, it is being invoked.

```
<bean id="abc" class="a.b.c.UtilClass" lazy-init="true" />
```

Can anyone please help me to stop calling class constructor at the startup? I want this to be called whenever it is needed.

Comment: You can't *create* a bean without running its' constructor, that doesn't make sense (creating a bean == instanciating a new instance of its class, which includes executing its constructor). You could however use a singleton or whatever-scoped bean to reuse the same bean instance over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This typically means there is a dependency on your bean that is also being instantiated.  The classic chain of dependencies is a singleton that must be loaded (e.g. a Spring MVC controller) that references a service bean, that then references DAO bean, so they must all be instantiated.

`@Lazy` or `lazy-init` beans come in more useful if they are referenced from prototype or session beans, or from beans that are created at runtime via an `ObjectFactory`.

If in doubt how the dependency chain is reaching your bean, try putting a breakpoint in the constructor.  There are typically some `resolveDependency()` methods in the calling stack in BeanFactory classes (e.g. `DefaultListableBeanFactory`).  Have a look for such as `beanName` variable values in there.